# Adding traits with keyword names in python

Tags: python, enthought, traits

I'm using [Enthought's traits library](http://docs.enthought.com/traits/index.html) and I have an object that looks like:

```
from traits import HasTraits, Str, Enum, Bool

class Parameter(HasTraits):
    name = Str()
    description = Str()
    required = Bool()
    _in   = Enum(["query", "header", "path", "formData", "body"])
```

However, I'd like to use the name `in` since I'm copying a specification from an external source. `in` is a keyword in python so I can't simply use:

```
class Parameter(HasTraits):
    in   = Enum(["query", "header", "path", "formData", "body"])
```

How can I add a trait with the name `in` (or other keywords like `class` or `print`)?

Comment: You might be able to do it *after* the class definition, i.e. `setattr(Parameter, 'in', Enum(...))`. But note that you won't be able to access it as a regular attribute, only via e.g. `getattr`.

Comment: Just like you did. Add an underscore. A reserved word is a reserved word. (Even if this is possible somehow I don't think you should do it.)

Comment: @jonrsharpe It appears if you do that all your access would correspondingly have to be with `getattr` because `obj.in` is a Syntax Error (tested with 2.7 and 3.4)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I'm brand new to the traits module but I can show you my use case -- I'm trying to model the swagger object described here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameterObject if there is a better way to do this I would be happy to hear it!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist yes, that's correct; it still won't let *"regular"* `thing.keyword` attribute access work.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist is there anything that `add_class_trait()` might help with?

Comment: @Hooked I'm suggesting adding an underscore is exactly the normal way of doing what you're suggesting. As an example, look at [SqlAlchemy's use of `in_` and `is_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_).

Comment: As far as appending an underscore does, it's also what's done in `Tkinter` for `from_`, etc, so there's plenty of precedent in the standard library, as well.

Comment: [operator.is_](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.is_), [operator.and_](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.and_). The other thing I see is minor misspellings ('klass', 'cls', 'obj', etc) but I'm not fan